# Get the memory needed to store a tensor in PyTorch

Tags: memory, pytorch, tensor

```py
import torch
import sys

a = torch.rand(10)
b = torch.rand(100)

sys.getsizeof(a) # 72
sys.getsizeof(a.storage()) # 88
a.element_size() * a.nelement() # 40

sys.getsizeof(b) # 72
sys.getsizeof(b.storage()) # 448
b.element_size() * b.nelement() # 400
```

After a Google search I found that people use one of these 3 methods, but they all return 3 different outputs.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [PyTorch discussion forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-know-the-memory-allocated-for-a-tensor-on-gpu/28537/2):

> `sys.getsizeof()` will return the size of the python object. It will the
> same for all tensors as all tensors are a python object containing a
> tensor. For each tensor, you have a method `element_size()` that will
> give you the size of one element in byte. And a function `nelement()`
> that returns the number of elements. So the size of a tensor `a` in
> memory (cpu memory for a cpu tensor and gpu memory for a gpu tensor)
> is `a.element_size() * a.nelement()`.

Therefore, the (simple) answer appears to be as follows, and holds true when calculating expected memory usage and release in various scenarios:

```
a.element_size() * a.nelement()
```

This is supported by experimenting with the following:

```
torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.int8).element_size()   # 1 (byte)
torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.int16).element_size()  # 2 (bytes)
torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.int32).element_size()  # 4 (bytes)
```

Additionally, [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-know-the-memory-allocated-for-a-tensor-on-gpu/28537/15) offers a more detailed way to calculate the memory usage.